# Need help in fetching document with reference id in firestore using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a newbie with firestore and reactjs. I'm trying to write a simple react code to fetch documents from 2 collections

user-habits {email, habitid}

habits {habitid, content +few more fields}

> each user can have one or more habits

I'm trying to execute the following react code to

```
export async function getHabit(habitid) {
    let result = [];
    return db.collection('habits')
    .where('habitid','==',`${habitid}`)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            result.push({...doc.data()})
        })
        return result;
    })
}
 
export async function getUserHabit(email) {
    let result = [];
    return db.collection('user-habits')
    .where('email','==',`${email}`)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let habitid = doc.data().habitid
            let habit = getHabit(habitid)
            result.push({...doc.data(), ...habit, uid:doc.id})
        })
        return result;
    })
}
```

For some reason, I always get blank data on getHabit call. console log statement, shows that a Promise is returned by getHabit, which resolves after the code is completely executed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you are using `async` functions, this can all be done a lot easier with `await` instead of callbacks with `then`.  Your code will need to handle that promise returned by getHabit, since all async functions return a promise.

Comment: Thans Doug, I already tried with async and await, For some reason unknown to me :( the behaviour was same

Comment: It is a one-one relation between user-habits and habits, my requirement is to get all the fields in one single object. Any other approach to address this is welcome

Comment: You can't avoid writing code to handle the promise returned by getHabit.  Start with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` and `await` inside the `getUserHabit()` function to wait for the promise returned by `getHabit()` to be resolved

```
export async function getUserHabit(email) {
    let result = [];
    return db.collection('user-habits')
    .where('email','==',`${email}`)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(async doc => {
            let habitid = doc.data().habitid
            let habit = await getHabit(habitid)
            console.log(habit) // will log the habit value
            result.push({...doc.data(), ...habit, uid:doc.id})
        })
        return result;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `return` the `db.collection` in this case. Since you're calling from the front end, you can just reference the `collection` path and wait for Firestore to return what you're looking for. Also, you don't need to use the `.then()` approach with async/await. If you're expecting an array in return, try something like this:

```
export async function getHabit(habitid) {
    let result = [];
    let get = await db.collection('habits').where('habitid','==',`${habitid}`).get()
    get.forEach(doc => {
       result.push({...doc.data()})
    })
      return result;
  })
}
 
export async function getUserHabit(email) {
    let result = [];
    let get = await db.collection('user-habits').where('email','==',`${email}`).get()
    get.forEach(doc => {
       let habitid = doc.data().habitid
       let habit = getHabit(habitid)
       result.push({...doc.data(), ...habit, uid:doc.id})
     })
      return result;
 })
}
```